# How to abstract the database layer?

Tags: c#, database, ado.net

Every time I get something from the db, my code is this:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.v3ConnString))
            {
                conn.Open();
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand())
                {
                    command.Connection = conn;
                    command.CommandText = "SELECT ...";
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("...", ...);
                    using (SqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        if (dr.HasRows)
                            someVar = true;
                  }
                }
            }
```

Instead I want to do `myArray = Db.sql("SELECT ...")` or something else if there is a better way. Can somebody point me in the right direction?

EDIT: I'm not looking for code to generate SQL for me, rather an easy way of getting an array result from an SQL query.

Comment: You could read about DAO's http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout [Dapper.NET](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/). It's a lightweight ORM which will simplify this task.

Comment: would not agree to this - stackoverflow uses it and it is one of the most stable/fastest evolving sites written on .net. Also there is Massive, which also started not long time ago, so they are not outdated, just different approach to things.

Answer (score 3):

That's "the old way of doing it". If you're working with a newer version of the framework (>2.0) then please use linq to sql. You have a very good tutorial here: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/05/19/using-linq-to-sql-part-1.aspx

Comment: No thanks. I can write good SQL statements and don't want something to automatically generate them for me.

Comment: @IgorK I can write very good assembly, yet I routinely let C compiler do it for me. You cannot have your cake and eat it too: you either abstract out your database layer, or you write your own SQL and stay tightly coupled to your database.

Comment: I'm ok to stay coupled with the db, presume all I'm asking for then is how to convert a SqlDataReader object into a 2D array or List, as I can then put this into a static class/method.

Comment: @IgorK If that's all you need, then Darin Dimitrov's answer is ideal for you.

Comment: @IgorK: I can also write good sql statements but that does not mean that linq does not make my life easier. Give it a go, you'll like it.

Answer (score 1):

1. [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa697427%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)
2. [NHibernate](http://nhforge.org/Default.aspx)
3. [Linq 2 SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb425822.aspx) (distant third, because it is in maintenance mode).

Comment: I would definitely add Telerik's OpenAccess ORM tool to this list.  It has more features than EF and supports more than EF with native SQL Server 2008 data types (geolocation).  \

Comment: @tsells what's the point? The OP does not seem to want any of it, he wants to write his own SQL :) In addition, Telerik is not free, making it harder to recommend.

Comment: Telerik OpenAccess is free. http://www.telerik.com/community/promos/freestuff.aspx

Answer (score 1):

NHibernate is one of the most powerful ORMs frameworks. Using NHibernate you still can write SQL queries, however NHibernate will take the job of data transformation from Sql types to .net types.

Frankly speaking in your situation there is no difference to use ORM or not. If you repeat your code from time to time it means that your application has very bad design and you need to improve it.
Firstly, you should divide yours application on several layers(I'm speaking only about database access).

1. Layer which provides with ability to execute custom sql queries, you will use this code from another layers.
2. Layer which  provides you with beautiful interface and encapsulate all database logic, including queries and objects transformation.

and so on. you can add settings layer which will read connection string from settings, but it is all optional.